# How to benchmark '&' vs '%' cost correctly, using JMH

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

So here is the simple thing I am trying to test, what is faster a mod operation or a AND one (assuming power of two) - this is what hashMap does internally. Is this a correctly spelled "test"?  I have to admit that the internals of jmh and getting to write a correct micro benchmark after going through all the samples (for the 3-rd time I think) is quite a challenge. :)

```
   @State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MeasureSpeedModuleVsAnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(MeasureSpeedModuleVsAnd.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .warmupIterations(1)
                .measurementIterations(5)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(2))
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();

    }

    @Param({ "16", "32", "256", "1048576" /* 2 power of 10 */ })
    public int number_of_buckets;

    @Param({ "345984", "123456", "111", "98653" })
    public int hashcode;

    @Benchmark
    public int benchamark_modulo() {
        return hashcode % number_of_buckets;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int benchmark_and() {
        return (number_of_buckets - 1) & hashcode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, of course not, `arg % 33` != `(arg - 1) & 33`. Take `42` as the example...

Comment: You wanted to write `arg % 32` and `arg & (32 - 1)`?

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev totally my bad, copied the wrong code.

Comment: @Eugene: I'm sorry, but WHAT THE HELL. `32453667 % arg` is a real hash function? `(arg - 1) & 32453667` is supposed to do what? `32453667` is neither prime, nor a power of two, nor a power of two minus one. What. The. Hell. I am uber-confused.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev I am not talking about a hash function at all. **(n-1) & hash** is semantically the same **hash % n**; if n is power of two, the result for positive numbers is the same. this is how a bucket in hashmap is chosen, all I wanted to test is the speed difference of these two. Now, I am the one uber-confused.

Comment: But, in your code, it's called out as "arg", not as "modulo", which it apparently is. And swapping operands for `&` only adds to confusion. `hash % modulo` = `hash & (modulo - 1)`, if modulo is a power of two, indeed.

Comment: I also don't get how you somersault between making a modulo constant in previous version, and now the hash itself is a constant? In realistic HashMap cases, neither is constant.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev this is taken from hashmap, but it does not test the actual hashmap. It's a simple speed difference computation. The thing I was **mostly** interested is the correctness of the actual jmh set-up.

Comment: And I am telling you: tests with constant hashes are different from the tests with constant modulos, and are different from tests with non-constant hashes and modulos. Every one of those variants is "correct", in the sense that it measures something. But are they measure what *you* actually want to measure? Only you can answer. If you are not sure, try *all* of them. And by "try" I mean both "measure" and "analyze" what is going on and why they produce different/same results.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev great comment! You should actually make it an answer; that is what I wanted to hear. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in detail in this blog post: http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.za/2014/11/the-mythical-modulo-mask.html

Your benchmark is broken (comparing what seems like irrelevant quantities) because you are comparing (non_final_field & constant) with (constant % non_final_field). Replace with (non_final_field1 % non_final_field2) and (non_final_field1 & (non_final_field2-1)) where non_final_field2 is a power of 2.

In the context of HashMap the value is used to read from an array and the blog post covers the implications of that side as well.